# Prove that $Z_n=(X_{n-1},X_n)$ is a Markov chain, where $X_n$ is a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I’m trying solve this Problem:
Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ a Markov chain with States set $S=\{0,1\}$ and transition probability matrix
$$P=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1-a& a\\
b& 1-b
\end{array}
\right).$$
Define a new stochastic process $(Z_n)_{n\geq 1}$ by $Z_n=(X_{n-1},X_n)$.
Argue that $(Z_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a Markov chain and write down its transition matrix.

**My solution**

First I found the states space of $(Z_n)_{n\geq 1}$, which  clearly is $E=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$.

For prove that is Markov chain I verified that satisfy the Markov property as follow
$$
\begin{split}
P(Z_{n+1}=(i_n,i_{n+1})|Z_{1}&=(i_0,i_{1}),Z_{2}=(i_1,i_{2}),\ldots,Z_{1}=(i_{n-1},i_{n}))=\\
&=\dfrac{P((X_n,X_{n+1})=(i_n,i_{n+1}),(X_0,X_1)=(i_0,i_{1}),\ldots, (X_{n-1},X_n)=(i_{n-1},i_n))}{P((X_0,X_1)=(i_0,i_{1}),\ldots, (X_{n-1},X_n)=(i_{n-1},i_n))}\\
&=\dfrac{P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1},X_n=i_n,\ldots,X_0=i_0)}{P(X_n=i_n,\ldots,X_0=i_0)}\\
&=\dfrac{P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}|X_n=i_n,\ldots,X_0=i_0)P(X_n=i_n,\ldots,X_0=i_0)}
{P(X_n=i_n,\ldots,X_0=i_0)}\\
&=P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}|X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},X_n=i_n)\\
&=P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1},X_n=i_n|X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},X_n=i_n)\\&=P(Z_{n+1}=(i_n,i_{n+1})|Z_n=(i_{n-1},i_n)),
\end{split}
$$
I supposed that the states have to be consecutive because in other case the $P(X_n=i_n,\ldots,X_0=i_0)=0$. Therefore $(Z_n)$ is a Markov chain. Now my problem for find the transition probabilities:

**My problem**

For find transition probabilities I have problems because the rown en transition matrix for $(Z_n)$ doesn't sum 1 and seems the transitions probabilies are the same of the chain $(X_n)$. For instante, consider

$P(Z_2=(0,0)|Z_1=(0,0))=P(X_2=0|X_1=0,X_0=0) = P(X_2=0|X_1=0)=1-a$ (Using Markov property)

$P(Z_2=(0,0)|Z_1=(1,0))=P(X_2=0|X_1=0,X_0=1) = P(X_2=0|X_1=0)=1-a$

$P(Z_2=(0,0)|Z_1=(1,1))=P(X_2=0|X_1=1,X_0=1) = 0$

$P(Z_2=(0,0)|Z_1=(0,1))=P(X_2=0|X_1=1,X_0=0) = 0$

Someone can explain me what's wrong with my solution and help me to solve that please.

Comment: There's no reason that $\sum_i P(Z_2 = j \mid Z_1 = i)$ should equal $1$.  This is the sum of the column, not the row, of the transition matrix.  (you have some other errors, but this is the error in your logic)

Comment: That's correct, I was thinking wrong the transition probabilities, thank you for your observation :). What other errors did you observe?